# Find an entity that exactly containing a list of provided id (of the other entity) in a many-to-many relation on MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, search, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 tables:

- **Recipes** (id, name)
- **Recipes_Ingredients**(id, fk_recipe, fk_ingredient, quantity)
- **Ingredients** (id, name)

I need to find all the recipes that containing exactly a provided list of ingredients ID.

Es:

I provide a list of ingredients id like **111 (salt), 222(pepper), 333(oil)** and I need to find all the recipes that have **ONLY** these ingredients.

**So if a recipe has those ingredients (the id list I provided) + other ingredients, it doesn't have to show**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT fk_recipe
FROM Recipes_Ingredients
GROUP BY fk_recipe
HAVING SUM(fk_ingredient IN (111,222,333)) = COUNT(*)
```